# Is there a default mechanism for getting a flat string representation of an XML Node?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I don't want to use jQuery for the following:

If I had the following XML

```
<parent>
    <a >some text
      <b propA="foo">some more text

      </b>
      and more text still
    </a>
   </parent>
```

and wanted to call something like

//pseudo... I pass in node 1 because node 0 is a useless empty text node...

getFlatXMLAsString(parent.childNodes[1])

and receive a string that looked like `"<a>some text\n<b propA="foo">some more text\n\n</b>and more text still</a>"`

Notice how it just converts the XML to a flat string, but includes the node's own opening and closing tags (and if that had attributes, it would have those in there as well).

Obviously I can do this manually but was hoping there's some built in mechanism that would prevent me re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel You just want to remove the newlines and replace them with `\n`? Or is there anything else that needs to be done.

Comment: no no... I want the full stringified representation of <a> (including all it's attributes)... nodeValue stops as soon as it encounters another child Element Node... I want it to treat it like a document node and just give me the whole shebang (but only from the node I pass in down).. so, in my example, I pass in <a> and get all of <a>'s children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox) the cross-browser way to do this looks like

```
function outerHTML(node){
    // if IE, Chrome take the internal method otherwise build one
  return node.outerHTML || (
  function(n){
      var div = document.createElement('div'), h;
      div.appendChild( n.cloneNode(true) );
      h = div.innerHTML;
      div = null;
      return h;
  })(node);
  }
```

That is if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In Mozilla and Webkit browsers, you can use the [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer). Just do an object-test.

I'm not aware of what facilities are available in other browsers, but they might have one.

Worst case scenario, you'll have to write a function to do this by hand which walks all the nodes and writes to a string.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856138/1002469) should get you started.

Comment: I don't think this does what I'm asking for. Notice that I'm looking to get a flattened version of the XML that is a child of the node I pass in, including all the brackets and attributes and everything. I'm not looking to strip out the internal nodes, I'm looking to get a flattened String representation of them.  In my question I provide an example of what I'd expect to get back from my function, given the passed in node.

Comment: Ah, you want to serialize the XML? Unfortunately this is going to depend on what environment you're in. Are you executing this JS in a browser?

Comment: I am. And as you imagine, it has to be cross-browser. I'm starting to suspect that I should just roll my own... it's a really simple recursive method, in fact, I've written it before, years ago.  Also, it looks like since IE treats XML the same as DOM, I may be able to just call for innerHMTL on the parent node to get what I want. I don't think that'll work in any non crap browser though :)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no generic cross-browser way to do this. I've changed my answer to point you to what's out there.  I imagine serialization from the DOM is easy in principle (recursive loops) but tricky in practice (entities, inline DTDs, odd corner cases).